# Catch (date) change event of iOS5 native datepicker per JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios5, dom-events, uidatepicker

I try to catch a date change event per JavaScript of the native iOS5 datepicker.

Example:

```
<input type="date" onclick="alert('click')" onchange="alert('change')" onselect="alert('select')" onfocus="alert('focus')" />
```

The `onfocus` and `onclick` events are fired correctly (tested on iPad with iOS 5.0.1) but
not the `onchange` or `onselect` events (not while you turn at the wheel, either if the control lost the focus).

Anybody has idea, how to catch these events?

Edit:

I tried also the `onblur` event to catch the lost of the focus:

```
<input type="date" onblur="alert('blur')" />
```

But that crashes Safari.